# LAST_INSERT_ID() gives wrong ID

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

To put it simply, I have a function that first creates a row in a table in my database, and then fetches the last row (last inert) from that table:

```
fdb.create("""INSERT INTO _paused_jobs (_job_id, _pause_reason_id, _pause_start, _status_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (_job_id, _pause_reason_id, _pause_start, _status_id))
_pause = fdb.read("""SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()""", (), False)
```

I am using SQLAlchemy, and here is the code for the create and read methods respectively:

```
def create(self, query_string, query_params):
    try:
        connection = self.engine.connect()
        connection.execute(query_string, query_params)
        connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)
    finally:
        pass


def read(self, query_string, query_params = (), fetchall = True):
    try:
        connection = self.engine.connect()
        data = connection.execute(query_string, query_params)
        connection.close()
        if fetchall: 
            data = data.fetchall()
            if len(data) < 1:
                return None
            data = [dict(row) for row in data]
            for d in data:
                for field in d:
                    if type(d[field]) == type(datetime.datetime.now()) and not d[field] is None:
                        d[field] = d[field].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        else:
            data = data.fetchone()
            if type(data) is type(None):
                return None
            data = dict(data)
            for field in data:
                if type(data[field]) == type(datetime.datetime.now()) and not data[field] is None:
                    data[field] = data[field].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)
    finally:
        pass
```

Nothing too complicated as you can see. The _id field is an `AI PK int` field. So you'd expect that when I run the first code snippet, I'd create a new row in the `_paused_jobs` table, and then fetch it and assign it to the `_pause` variable, right? But, it doesn't always work that way.

So then i just printed the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and saw a pattern where it sometimes prints the `_id` of the last `_paused_jobs` insert, but other times prints the `_id` of the insert before that.

So I concluded that the two queries are actually executed in parallel, and if the second query executes before the first one, it will not give the correct `last_insert_id()`

What is the best way of solving this?

Comment: You should run both statements in the *same transaction*, now they're running in separate transactions. Looking at the code you rely on SQLAlchemy's soft autocommit feature, you should define your transaction boundaries explicitly instead.

Comment: So I should run both queries in the same transaction? Okay. \n
How do i explicitly tell SQLAlchemy when it should commit though?

Comment: NVM, I figured it out. Turns out connection.begin() is actually what returns a Transaction object. And the commit() method should be called on the Transaction, not the Connection. My bad, I had things mixed up. Sorry :/. Turns out spending 5/10 minutes on reading the docs does wonders xD.